# How to secure credentials stored in source control for use by Visual Studio Online build controllers

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I have a PowerShell script that executes after the code is compiled. This script connects to a remote machine and transfers the files and then deploys them onto that remote machine. My script needs the credentials for that remote machine. Since all of this is stored in TFS, this means that the credentials are available to anyone who has access to the TFS instance in visualstudio.com

I've done some reading, and most solutions involve storing the decryption key on the build server (in a file, as an environment variable, etc). This is fine if I own/control the build server, but I am using hosted build servers. If I put the keys in my source control, then that defeats the entire purpose of encrypting the values in the first place.

Is there something I'm missing here? Am I approaching this problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 0):

as long as you are using the Build-System of TFS you're always having security issues. Everyone who's able to trigger a build in any way is able to access source control of the whole collection even if he's not allowed to do by permissions.

Even the method storing the decryption key on the build server isn't secure, because in a unittest a developer is able to access the local disk of the build server using the build accounts credentials.

So if you use the tfs build system you mostly have to trust your developers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have some good points, especially around executing unit tests. Virtually all encryption is "good enough" security. Given enough time, any cipher can be cracked, but is the length of time required to crack it short enough to make it worth the effort? As long as the answer is 'no', then it's "good enough". It's not uncommon for someone who isn't on the project to request copy of the source code, so I'm mainly interested in keeping the encryption keys out of source control, so we don't give it to them accidentally.